# netsh set IP address adaptor name conflict

Tags: batch-file, ip-address, lan, netsh

I use the following netsh command when setting the IP address of the LAN Adaptor within a batch file.

```
netsh int ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static address=10.000.0.1 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=none
```

I have recently encountered an issue where the batch-file was run on a different system and this has failed to work (returning Element Not Found), I found the cause of the issue to be the adaptor was labelled 'Ethernet'.

This works fine providing the adaptor is labelled as 'Local Area Connection' and the easy fix is to rename the adaptor.

However i would like a solution where it isnt required to rename and the command works on any system irrelevant of how the LAN Adaptor is labelled on that system.

Is this possible?

Comment: `For /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('netsh interface show interface') Do @Echo %A`

Comment: @Mark That will not work if the interface name has spaces. but this will work `for /f "skip=3tokens=3*" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface') do echo %%j`